# автоматическое обновление переменной в C++

Tags: c++

Как мне сделать так, что-бы через определенное время какая-нибудь переменная обновлялась сама и при этом чтобы код работал дальше.

Например чтобы, пока мой код выполняет какие-то свои функции,  параллельно увеличивалась переменная каждую секунду.

Comment: Поток с таймером?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Многопоточный вариант с мьютексом:

```
#include <thread>
#include <mutex>
#include <iostream>

/// глобальная переменная
int g_i = 0;
/// мьютекс, защищающий g_i
std::mutex g_i_mutex;

///
/// \brief потокобезопасный инкремент
///
void safe_increment()
{
    /// после выхода из функции мьютекс автоматически разблокируется
    std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock(g_i_mutex);
    ++g_i;
}

///
/// \brief потокобезопасный геттер
/// \return глобальная переменная
///
int save_get()
{
    /// после выхода из функции мьютекс автоматически разблокируется
    std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock(g_i_mutex);
    return g_i;
}

///
/// \brief основная функция главного потока, имитирующая
/// выполнение длительных вычислений
///
void longTimeCalculation()
{
    while (true)
    {
        std::cout << "globalValue from longTimeCalculation function: " << save_get() << std::endl;
        std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::seconds(3));
    }
}

///
/// \brief функция "фонового" потока, меняющая значение глобальной переменной
///
void changeValue()
{
    while (true)
    {
        std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::seconds(1));
        safe_increment();
    }
}

int main()
{
   std::thread t1(changeValue);
   longTimeCalculation();
   t1.join();
   return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Вы сами написали главное слово - **параллельно**.

Организуйте отдельный поток, который будет увеличивать ее значение. Только не забудьте о том, что при параллельном доступе надо принять соответствующие меры - например, защитить обращение к переменной семафором.

Answer (score 1):

```
int i = 0;
while (true)
{
    Sleep(1000);    //задержка в 1000 миллисекунд (1 секунда)
    i++; // или что вы там хотели делать с вашей переменной?
    std::cout << "Message : " << i << std::endl;

}
```

PS вообще есть много вариантов решения данной проблемы http://www.cyberforum.ru/cpp-beginners/thread1149197.html